# Error when deploying database.yml with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

I have added `config/database.yml` to my `.gitignore` file. And have added this to the deploy.rb file

```
namespace(:customs) do
   task :symlink_db, :roles => :app do
    run "cp #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
end
after "deploy:update_code", "customs:symlink_db"
```

But now that i run `cap deploy`. I get the error

`No such file or directory - /var/www/XXXX/releases/20130313100825/config/database.yml`

How do i fix it ?

Note: there has already been a release before this. I made some changes to the app and deploying it again.

Thanks

Comment: Despite the error, you are not linking the file, you are copying it. Perhaps you want to change that.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a symlink, as it will not care if the source file is not there yet.

```
task :symlink_db_yml do
  run "ln -s #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
end
```

And you want to execute it before bundle:install, as the new application directory is not created at the deploy:update_code stage.

```
before 'bundle:install', 'customs:symlink_db_yml'
```